# Cannot redirect my application to use PDB file in bin folder

Tags: .net, dll, gac, pdb-files

I have done about a day of research on this after banging my head against the same issue for the past couple of days and nothing I try seems to work.  I'm starting to think this is impossible.

I am trying to debug an old application.  I am able to debug a few projects within the solution but others are giving me an issue in which they are unable to load the corresponding .pdb file.  It seems that the application is trying to look for the .pdb file in the GAC but when I look for the assembly in the GAC, it is nowhere to be found (so I don't know why it would look there).

I tried to force the application to look for the pdb in my bin folder but I get a different error message that says "PDB does not match image".  Even though the .dll & .pdb file are both in the bin folder.

I've also tried to redirect the version of my project but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Modules, locate the DLL in the list, right-click and select "Symbol Load Information".  Tells you where it looked for the PDB.  Not otherwise a fix for having the time-stamps on the DLL and the PDB files out of sync, not uncommon with old apps.  Be sure to rebuild the project so you get fresh files.

Comment: I've tried this.  Does not work.  No matter what, I get either, "PDB does not match image" or "Cannot find PDB".